# Why does sp_refreshview raise an exception on views that are not schema bound?

Tags: sql-server, exception, view, refresh

I am connected to a SQL Server 2012 instance using a login with the sysadmin role, but when I run the following script I get this exception for every view:

> Msg 15165, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal,
>   Line 55
>   Could not find object <view name> or you do not have permission.

Note that I am filtering out any schema-bound views:

```
DECLARE @ViewName NVARCHAR(max);

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD TYPE_WARNING FOR
    SELECT  s.name + '.' + v.name
      FROM  sys.views v
            JOIN sys.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id
     WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(v.object_id, 'IsSchemaBound') = 0;

OPEN myCursor;
RAISERROR('Refreshing views:', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

WHILE (1=1) BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ViewName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK;

    RAISERROR(@ViewName, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_refreshview @ViewName;
END;

RAISERROR('Done', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
CLOSE       myCursor;
DEALLOCATE  myCursor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like sp_refreshview should be run from the database that houses the view. So change the execute line to:

```
 EXEC dbo.sp_refreshview @ViewName;
```